# how to insert data to two table in a single controller using DB::Tranactions

Tags: php, laravel

i want to register a user and insert data to the account table and also insert account's user_id as the created user id, i doing this from my admin controller;

```
public function store(StoreUsersRequest $request)
    {

        DB::transaction(function($request)
        {
            $newUser = User::create($request->all());

            $newAccounts = Accounts::create([
                'user_id' => $newUser->id,
                'balance' => '0',
                'amt' => '0',
            ]);

            if( !$newAccounts )
            {
                throw new \Exception('accounts not created for new user');
            }
        });
        return redirect()->route('users.create');
    }
```

Can anyboby show me how please?

Comment: You are using mass assignments, have you checked that all the fields on the appropriate models are notated in the respective models fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. I have assumed your table name as "accounts"

```
$result = DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
  $data = new User;
  $data->name = $request->name;
  $data->other_values = $request->values;
  $data->save();
  DB::table('accounts')->insert(['user_id' => $data->id, 'balance' =>  '0', 'amount' => '0']);
  return true;
}, 5);

if($result) {
  // Redirect after successful execution
  return redirect()->route('users.create');
} else {
  // Redirect after unsuccessful execution
  Session::flash('failed','Oops, accounts not created for new user');
  return redirect()->route('previous.route');
}
```

In View file

```
@if (session('failed'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{ session('failed') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

Comment: I want to create a new user and insert the value to the account table. Does the function also create a new user

Comment: yes, give it a try. i am using this code in one of my project

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();

    $newUser = User::create($request->all());

    $newAccounts = Accounts::create([
        'user_id' => $newUser->id,
        'balance' => '0',
        'amt' => '0',
    ]);

    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();

    throw new \Exception('accounts not created for new user');
}
```

Comment: it threw back this error **accounts not created for new user**

Comment: @TobyNwude you will not be able to locate the issue itself so try logging the exception. you are trying to create a user by passing whole request. have you checked the fillable part?

Comment: Yes I initially made the controller to only  create the user in the User table and it was working

Comment: @hamidAli how can I log the expection

Comment: try {
        // Validate the value...
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        report($e);

        return false;
    }